# How to detect errors that are rising only when the program is installed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm facing with some strange problems. From a while I have no error when testing the program with the project. But with installed program, even on my developing machine, I have strange errors that never happens with runs with the project.

I'm using VS 2013, Windows Forms application, vb.net language.

There is any settings in Visual studio that make the program to jump over and to not consider those errors with the program running from Visual Studio ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you include the full exception message that you get for one or more of those errors? There is no way that we're going to be able to help you without more information.

Comment: I have a big program. In project running time there are no errors. In the installed runtime version there are rising errors in very different lines of code, almost random line of code. I'm using multithreading and I think there are not threading safe line of code. Sometimes a line of code rise an error, sometimes not. So I want to get those errors in a project runtimes. There are very different, so I cannot put an example here because tomorrow will be another error, on another line.

Comment: So the situation is general, as I described it. For a particular situation I'll put a particular question, is no need to vote down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most famous errors that can happen in your case is missing dlls/outdated dlls so you can copy all the dlls from your bin/debug folder into the folder of exe that causes issues ,if it fixes it , then it's a dll issue,if not then it's something wrong with the installer

Comment: I have all dlls. I 've deployed using .pdb files and so I have the line of code where error rise with the installed program, and is nothing missing with dlls, but I don't understand why those errors doesn't rise in Visual Studio program testing time.

Comment: if that's the case go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > check if the error you are getting is checked